# How can a thread get to cgroup v1 if not directly written there?

Tags: linux, cgroup

I set `cpu.cfs_quota_us` of my cgroup v1 and write some threads of my process to `tasks` file. But I see that some threads that I do not write there explicitly, somehow find there way to the `tasks` file.

What may be the reason for that and how can I investigate it better (in a programming way, or using `/proc`, or in any other way)?